# file changes -- notification and diff

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, diff, textfiles

I'm looking for a way to be notified if a text file changes (Windows 7), and be offered a file diff upon such a change. For example, the text editor Notepad++ does part of this, notifying me of an external change (in a file currently open) and giving me the option of reloading it from disk or keep what's currently open:

[image: Notepad ++]

But I want to see the changes made in the new version, if any, so this isn't enough. Is there a relatively easy way to get this, perhaps a plugin for Notepad++ or another text editor with this feature? (Actually, I remember that the text editor SlickEdit had/has this feature, but perhaps there's another solution)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the compare plugin for this .

There is a quite easy tutorial at http://www.davidtan.org/how-to-compare-two-text-files-using-notepad-plus/

There is just one problem, you cannot open one file multiple times in Notepad++ . So you must click on Nein (No) in the dialog window. Then copy the old version to a different file or window and reopen the file again. Then you can compare them.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but I was looking for a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It is now possible with the Plugin "Compare Plus":

Click on "Nein" or "No" when you get the file changes notification.
Then you call the Plugin:
[image]

And it will show the differences side by side.